# where condition db array contain value Laravel Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

i have document like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
"primary" : [
    "0":{
         'abc',
         'xyz'
         }
        ]
 },
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("512e2898481asdf7asdf7"),
"primary" : [
    "0":{
         'xyz',
         'ght',
         'aaa'
         }
        ]
 }
```

here i want to get all records that contain 'xyz' in primary.0 array

also tried laravel whereIn and aggregate $in but no luck..

please suggest me solution in laravel or mongodb aggregate..

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, can you show the correct code?

Comment: [primary] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => xyz
        [2] => etc
    )
)
this is my primary column